# What is this status bar symbol that looks like combined ♺ and ⇵?

Tags: notification-bar, notification-icons, app-icons

Occasionally a symbol shows up in the status bar (top right) of my Samsung Galaxy S8+, but I can't figure out what's producing it or why.  Any insight?

[image]

Tapping it does nothing. Given the dashed "warning-style" triangle, and the "up/down" arrows, I would guess it's a synchronization error of some sort, but I don't know what it would be from.

Android symbol lists (like [this one](https://www.nextpit.com/status-notification-icons-meaning#statusbar)) don't seem to include this one.  Google Image search did return 2 sites that have matches (image shows in search result preview) but I couldn't actually find the image on either page: [this one](https://docplayer.net/203408619-User-manual-sm-g991b-sm-g991b-ds-sm-g996b-sm-g996b-ds-sm-g998b-sm-g998b-ds-english-01-2021-rev.html), and [this one](https://vsesam.org/page/22/?cat=-1) (which is Russian but oddly, won't translate).

[image]